# C# MDI - how do I prevent the scroll bar?

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi

Best shown with an image, I can drag the forms off the edge of the MDI parent, and scroll bars appear.

Id much rather that child forms are locked to the area of the Parent form.

Ive done searching for a solution, (A lot of these are answered 2+ years ago, so im hoping they are outdated) and only come across people checking co-ordinates on the Move event....  Great, but what if I have 20 forms.. or 100 forms. I cant code all of them, its a bit silly. Surely there is a property somewhere I can just set on the parent form.

[image: MDI Scrollbar problem]

Comment: This is key behavior of the native Windows MDI support code, you can't turn it off.  It is a windowing model from the previous century, back when users had low resolution monitors.  Consider another one.

Comment: @HansPassant, There are other ones ? :) Can you give an example please.

Comment: I don't know about "previous centry"; at least MS Excel 2007 is MDI (although half-disguised as a single-document interface, which bugs the hell out of me when you hit those cases when it becomes apparent that it's MDI). A lot of applications use single-document interfaces; the UIs of several different email clients (Thunderbird, Outlook, etc) look like a good fit for your basic UI model and lots of users will be familiar with the basic interaction model.

Comment: You might want to head on over to http://ux.stackexchange.com/ as well.

Comment: @Michael. Yes I just want to display one window at a time, but within the master form. Ill look into this SDI, any recommended links? thanks.

Comment: That's probably better posed as a separate question over on UX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like this...

Step !: you have to make base form( like user control)

and place this code in that form

```
 namespace Controls
 {
  public partial class BaseForm : Form
  {
    public BaseForm()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      StartPosition = FormStartPosition.WindowsDefaultLocation;
      MaximizeBox = false;
      Width = 806;
      //Width = 850;
      //Height = 760;
      Height = 730;
      //Width = 790;
      //Height = 617;
    }


    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
      const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
      const int SC_MOVE = 0xF010;
      //ShowScrollBar(this.Handle, (int)ScrollBarDirection.SB_BOTH, false);
      switch (m.Msg)
      {
        case WM_SYSCOMMAND:
          int command = m.WParam.ToInt32() & 0xfff0;
          if (command == SC_MOVE)
            return;
          break;
      }
      base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
  }
}
```

and then in every form you have to specify like this...

```
public partial class childform : BaseForm
{
   .......
}
```

Make sure all your child forms size is should be size specified in base form

- minsize is 0,0
- max sixze is also 0,0
- startposition -    windowsdefaultlocation
- windowstate - normal

I hope it will helps you ..

Answer (score 3):

**Step 1:**
You should create a new class inherited from NativeWindow class and override its WndProc method.

**Step 2:**
In your MDI form create a new object of this new class and pass the MDIClient control to its constructor.

**Step 1 code:**

```
  internal class MyNativeMDIclient : NativeWindow
    {
        private MdiClient mdiClient;

        public MyNativeMDIclient(MdiClient parent)
        {
            mdiClient = parent;
            ReleaseHandle();
            AssignHandle(mdiClient.Handle);            
        }
        internal void OnHandleDestroyed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ReleaseHandle();
        }
        private const int SB_BOTH = 3;
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern int ShowScrollBar(IntPtr hWnd, int wBar, int bShow);
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            ShowScrollBar(m.HWnd, SB_BOTH, 0 /*false*/);
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }
```

**Step 2 code:**

```
  foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
            {
                if (control is MdiClient)
                {
                    MyNativeMDIclient nw = new MyNativeMDIclient((MdiClient)control);
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always override the move functionality in a parent class, then have all of your forms inherit from that class.

Theres no magic API/property (that I know of, apologies if I'm wrong) to tell an MDI parent to lock children within its bounds.